# Skip locked GORM objects when finding

Tags: grails, grails-orm, psql

Is there any way to exclude locked objects in a `findAllBy` query in `Grails`?

Scenario:

I have two instances of a single grails-app that share the same database. I want to be able to lock some rows so that the if one instance is updating these rows the other instance won't be able to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Dynamic finders like `findAllBy*` do not support excluding locked objects.

Comment: I thought as much. I might as well try native sql.